# Creation of DataFrame from some numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm new using Python and I'm having some problems with the pandas DataFrame creation from numpy arrays.

I have 3 arrays:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30])
b = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20])
x = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1])
```

I need to construct a Dataframe where x should be the name of the columns, and it will have 5 rows named (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5). And the DataFrame should be fulfilled with the values of the array.

x | 0.1|0.2|0.3|....

---

x1 |  2  |  4  |  6 ....

---

x2 |  2  |  4  |  6 ....

---

x3 |  3  |  6  |  9 ....

---

x4 |  3  |  6  |  9 ....

---

x5 |  2  |  4  |  6 ....

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame([b, b, a, a, b], columns=x, index=['x{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(5)])
```

This gives:

```
    0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9  1.0
x1    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20
x2    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20
x3    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30
x4    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30
x5    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20
```